# Using comprehension list create a matrix with cross pattern

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Without using numpy I need to create a matrix that looks like this:

```
1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1
```

So far I have only been able to get this pattern:

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

using this comprehension list:

```
l = [[1 if i == j else 0 for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)]
```

Now I need to figure out how to change the counter diagonal to same pattern using comp list.

Comment: Just adding another condition with `i==j` which is `i+j==n-1`, where n is the range in either direction, which is what the indexes would show for the counter diagonal. I have added a solution accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  -

```
n=7
[[1 if i==j or i+j==n-1 else 0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void PatternCross()
        {

            for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
                {
                    if(row == j || row+j==n+1)
                    {
                        Console.Write("1");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write("0");

                    }

                }
               
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```